# Ajax (XHR) call from a http page to a https resource

Tags: javascript, ajax, same-origin-policy

Can a page that is on http make an Ajax (XHR) request to a https resource? For example a call from

```
http://mystore.com/somecrap.html 
to https://mystore.com/svc/AccountService.asmx/Payment.
```

If the only difference is the 'https', does it constitute a different origin?

According to these [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), it would seem that is not allowed but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Pretty sure you can trust the MDN. That's where a lot of people on this site get their info from anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Because the https runs with ssl but the http does not run,

so to make or provide  security, it makes two different behaviours and to load https data we have to call it from a https website with allowed cross origin resource sharing form the server site.